# Please, can anyone tell me how to clear the error of trim

Tags: jquery

I get the error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined
>           at Object.unlApp.Social.postCmtText
>           at commentSendbtn
>           at HTMLImageElement.onclick

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be helpful if you posted some code which others can use to reproduce the problem. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing trim operation to an undefined variable.
Try console.log(your variable)
Before doing trim.

Check browser console and you can see undefined. If yes, try to fill the variable and do trim. That will work